# corrupted size vs. prev_size Abortado (`core' generado) with function fclose

Tags: c, abort, fclose

i am trying to do script files to create and extract tarballs. It is code fro college and I am very new programming with c. Anyway, I can create a tarball, btw the problem comes when i wanted to extract, due to fclose function. Everything seems right and I can't find the issue.
All the program runs ok, but when I tried to close the tarFile with fclose(tarFile) it gives me thisa message:

Output:

```
corrupted size vs. prev_size
Abortado (`core' generado)
```

By debugging I detected where is the problem. It occurs when the header[i].size is assigned inside the readHeader function, in the for loop.

This error is the only thing i need to fix to finish the exercise, because the data from the tarball is copied correctly, but it is important to close de tarFile so i appreciate any type of help.

Thank you so much and sorry if i've been able to explain it better. This is my first post in stackoverflow and english is no my native language.

Here is the code

- Extract function

```c
/** Extract files stored in a tarball archive
 *
 * tarName: tarball's pathname
 *
 * On success, it returns EXIT_SUCCESS; upon error it returns EXIT_FAILURE. 
 * (macros defined in stdlib.h).
 *
 * HINTS: First load the tarball's header into memory.
 * After reading the header, the file position indicator will be located at the 
 * tarball's data section. By using information from the 
 * header --number of files and (file name, file size) pairs--, extract files 
 * stored in the data section of the tarball.
 *
 */
int
extractTar(char tarName[])
{
    //1. Load Headers
    FILE* tar = NULL;
    tar = fopen(tarName, "r");
    if(tar == NULL){
        printf ("Error al abrir el tarball\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    printf("ADDRES INIT: %p\n", &tar);
    int nFiles = 0;
    stHeaderEntry* header = NULL;
    //Carga el header y nFiles
    header = readHeader(tar, &nFiles);
    if(header == NULL || nFiles <= 0){
        printf("Error al crear header // NUM FILES: %d\n", nFiles);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    printf("Copiando...\n");
    
    //3. Copia de datos
    //Para este punto el tar debería apuntar a la sección de datos
    //por lo que se podría pasar a copiar los datos en función
    //del header anteriormente cargado
    FILE* output = NULL;
    for(int i = 0; i < nFiles; i++){
        output = fopen(header[i].name, "w");
        if(output == NULL){
            printf("Error al abrir output\n");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        int n = copynFile(tar, output, header[i].size);
        if(n == -1){
            printf("Error al copìar los datos en output\n");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

        if(fclose(output) != 0){
            printf("Error al cerra output\n");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
    }   


    printf("LLAMADA A FREE\n");
//-------------FREE_MEMORY-----------------------//
    printf("%s\n", header[0].name);
    for(int i = 0; i < nFiles; i++){
        printf("FREE HEADER NAME\n");
        free(header[i].name);
        header[i].name = NULL;
    }   
    
    printf("FREE HEADER\n");
    free(header);
    
    printf("CLOSE TAR\n");
    printf("ADDRES END: %p\n", &tar);
    if(fclose(tar) != 0){
        printf("Fallo al cerrar tarFile\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    
    printf("Extracción realizada con éxito\n");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

- readHeader Function

```c
/** Read tarball header and store it in memory.
 *
 * tarFile: pointer to the tarball's FILE descriptor 
 * nFiles: output parameter. Used to return the number 
 * of files stored in the tarball archive (first 4 bytes of the header).
 *
 * On success it returns the starting memory address of an array that stores 
 * the (name,size) pairs read from the tar file. Upon failure, the function returns NULL.
 */
stHeaderEntry*
readHeader(FILE * tarFile, int *nFiles)
{
    int nrFiles = 0;
    //Lectura de nFiles
    if((fread(&nrFiles, sizeof(int), 1, tarFile)) != 1){
        printf("Error al leer nFiles\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    
    //Reserva de memoria en función de nFiles
    stHeaderEntry* header = malloc(sizeof(stHeaderEntry) * (*nFiles));

    //Lectura de los datos del header
    char* str = NULL;
    
    int size = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < nrFiles; i++){
        //Primero el nombre
        str = loadstr(tarFile);
        if(str == NULL){
            return NULL;
        }
        
        header[i].name = malloc(sizeof(str) + 1);
        header[i].name = strcpy(header[i].name, str);
        header[i].name = strcat(header[i].name, "\0");
    
        
        //Segundo los bytes del archivo
        int n = fread(&size, sizeof(unsigned int), 1, tarFile);
        if(n != 1){
            printf("Error al leer header size\n");
            return NULL;
        }

        header[i].size = size;
    }       

    //Carga completa
    printf("READHEADER SUCCESSFUL\n");
    (*nFiles) = nrFiles;
    return header;
}
```

Comment: I think you should add the source code for the `loadstr` function; it's needed to be sure a posted answer will be correct (for example, we need to know if the string it returns is null-terminated).

Comment: @idz not sure why you deleted your answer - 'malloc(sizeof(str) + 1);' looks mighty suspicious to me, too, (str being a pointer).

Comment: It seems like `readHeader` is possibly mixing up `nFiles` and `nrFiles`?  You read `nrFiles` from the file, but then you allocate space for `header` based on `*nFiles`, which hasn't yet been modified and is still zero.  Having two variables with such similar names is probably a bad idea regardless.

Comment: @MartinJames because I think there is likely other stuff going on and without `loadstr` source it's hard to be sure. The fact that the OP is appending a null might mean that `str` us not null-terminated and then `strlen` is not the solution; `loadstr` would need to be modified. I mean `sizeof(str)` is definitely wrong, but it's only a partial answer.

Comment: Ok guys. I posted the loadstr function, so thank you all for your response

Comment: @NateEldredge was the answer about my problem hahaha everething comes from the name of nrFiles and nFiles, it is so important what you say about the nomenclature. 
Anymway, thanks all because of your advice and help

Answer (score 0):

In your `readHeader` function you allocate space for a string as follows:

```c
header[i].name = malloc(sizeof(str) + 1);
```

This will use the size of `str`, a string pointer which will be a constant value depending on the size of a pointer of you system (usually 4 or 8); this is not what you want.

You should be using `strlen` to calculate the length of the C string pointed to by `str`.

```c
header[i].name = malloc(strlen(str) + 1);
```

There is a problem in `loadstr` as well, since you only read one character into the buffer, you should change:

```c
    while((n = fread(buf, 1, 1, file)) != 0 && strcmp(buf, "\0") != 0){
        length++;
    }
```

to

```c
    while((n = fread(buf, 1, 1, file)) != 0 && buf[0] != '\0'){
        length++;
    }
```

otherwise `strcmp` might be reading from uninitialized memory.

A few other observations:

- You don't really need to copy the string since `loadstr` is allocating it, but if you do then you also need to free the return from `loadstr`.
- You don't need to null terminate the string after `strcpy` it will do it for you.
- Read up on `strncpy` it's a safer option than `strcpy`.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the tips,I have changed my code as you told me, but that didn't solve the problem because it was sillier than it seemed. In the comments of the question @NateEldredge had the key, because the name **nrFile** and **nFile** were confused in the readHeader function; it was a bad idea to name very similiar both variables.

Answer (score 0):

- loadstr contains this

```c
/** Loads a string from a file.
 *
 * file: pointer to the FILE descriptor 
 * 
 * The loadstr() function must allocate memory from the heap to store 
 * the contents of the string read from the FILE. 
 * Once the string has been properly built in memory, the function returns
 * the starting address of the string (pointer returned by malloc()) 
 * 
 * Returns: !=NULL if success, NULL if error
 */
char*
loadstr(FILE * file)
{
    char* str = NULL;
    char buf[1];
    int length = 0;
    int n = 0;
    //Asignación del tamaño del buffer
    while((n = fread(buf, 1, 1, file)) != 0 && strcmp(buf, "\0") != 0){
        length++;
    }
    
    str = malloc(length + 1);
    
    //Debido al while anterior, ahora file apunta a otro lado
    //Hay que hacer un rewind
    fseek(file, -(length + 1), SEEK_CUR);
    
    //Se guarda el nombre en str
    if(fread(str, length + 1, 1, file) != 1){
        printf("Error en loadstr\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    return  str;
}
```

I didn't post before because i thought it was unnecessary.

Comment: In `strcmp(buf, "\0")` any value in the 1-byte array `char buf[1];` except `0` will cause *undefined behaviour* when passed to `strcmp()`. The `length` you compute may not be correct and if `fseek(file, -(length + 1), SEEK_CUR);` is intended to rewind the file, then `rewind(file)` would be more reliable. (This code should really be added to the question, not as an answer)

Comment: Thanks @WeatherVane but i dont want to use rewind because it rewind the file to the begining and i dont want that. By the other hand, I will edit the question in te futur, that was a very fool mistake :P I am really new posting in this forum and i didn't see the edit button.